# How to add a sub-group to a boost property tree?

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to understand the syntax for boost property tree, but it's not jumping out at me.  I am using a boost property_tree to represent a simple json document. In one case, I want to construct such a document, so I have:

```
property_tree::wptree json;
json.put(_eventName.c_str(), L"");
```

And this works fine, but sometimes I want to include values underneath the event like:

> {   "event_name":    {
>       "time":"4pm",
>       "day":"saturday"   } }

What I *want* to do is:

```
property_tree::wptree json;
auto subTree = json.put(_eventName.c_str(), L"");
for(auto val : values)
  subTree.put(val->first.c_str(), val->second.c_str());
```

but this seems to throw an exception.  I've attempted to get a handle on this through the online docs, but I'm still a little unsure.  I'm thinking maybe the solution is to construct a new `wptree` with the sub values, and then add that tree to the json document, but that seems a bit counterintuitive to me.  Any advice?

Comment: Try `auto& subTree = json.put(...)`.

Comment: hmmm, interesting idea - will try tomorrow!